# Как определить логический контекст в Perl?

Tags: perl

Я знаю, что в Perl предусмотрено три основных контекста: скалярный, списочный, пустой. Внутри функции можно определить контекст вызываемого кода с помощью **wantarray** примерно так.

```
return unless defined wantarray; # don't bother doing more
my @a = complex_calculation();
return wantarray ? @a : "@a";
```

Кроме того, есть специальный подвид скалярного контекста — логический (встречается в условиях **if** или **grep**). И как определить, что моя функция вызвана в таком логическом контексте? В этом случае я бы мог оптимизировать вычисления.

Вот наглядный пример. Есть метод подсчёта количества строк в таблице из БД. Его можно использовать просто чтобы понять, есть ли хоть какие-то строки в той таблице. Понятно дело, что если метод так вызывается, то нет смысла сканировать всю таблицу, можно остановиться на первой подходящей строчке.

```
unless (логический контекст) {
    sql("SELECT count(*) FROM test_table WHERE some_colum > 42");
} else {
    sql("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test_table WHERE some_colum > 42)");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Want](https://metacpan.org/pod/Want) он может определять все тонкости текущего контекста.

```
use Want;

if (want('BOOL')) {
    sql("SELECT 1 FROM test_table WHERE some_colum > 42 LIMIT 1");
} else {
    sql("SELECT count(*) FROM test_table WHERE some_colum > 42");
}
```

Comment: _> At the moment want('BOOL') is true in either pure or pseudo boolean context._ Если верить описанию, то псевдологический контекст не различается. Для функции подсчёта это может быть фатальным.

Comment: @mymedia В чем конкретно проблема ? приведите пример где бы это могло повредить

Comment: Вроде всё ок. Меня немного смутила эта ремарка в документации. Но проблемы это и в самом деле не доставляет.